# Загрузка конфигурации

Tags: mysql

Помогите. Начинаю загружать mysql, всё норм, но когда начинает загружаться конфигурация (делать последние шаги), пишет, что не отвечает. Что делать?

Comment: ну как минимум привести лог загрузки.

Comment: на винде используешь?

Ставь линукс и непарься

Comment: да на виндосе 7

Comment: линукс уже есть,но как загружать программы на линукс?

Comment: lol ручками

Comment: я поставил альт линукс 3 дня назад.Когда  начинаю загружать у меня ничего не получается

Comment: а через wget можно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Повтори попытку! У меня [тут](http://ab-w.net/PHP/server_set.php) получилось поставить все с 1 раза.

Comment: спасибо большое вы мне очень помогли